# Computing mean waiting time

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

I have some problems with an exercise I'm doing right now (especially question b).

> There is an unemployed person looking for a job. $N$ is the random variable "number of months until a successful job offer occurs" with the understanding that $N=1$ if a succesful offer occurs in the first month. 
>   Let $q$ be the probability that NO successful job offer occurs. 
>   Denote $P(N=j)$ the probability that $N=j$ periods. Thus we have that $$P(N=1)=1-q, \,\,\,\,\, P(N=2)=q(1-q)$$

Now the two questions:

1. a) Compute $P(N=i)$: I think this should be: $q^{(i-1)}(1-q)$ right?
2. b) What is the mean waiting time?

**Hint:** If $S(x) = \sum x^n$ is the geometric series, consider the derivative of $S(x)$ with respect to $x$.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you learned about the expected value of a random variable?

Comment: I have but I don't see how this might help me in this question...?

Answer (score 4):

The mean waiting time is given by the expected value of the random variable $N$:

$$E[N] = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} i \cdot P[N = i] = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} i \cdot q^{i-1}(1-q)$$

The first equality follows from the definition of expected value. The last equality follows from substituting the expression you found for $P[N = i]$ in part a) of the question. Notice that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} i \cdot q^{i-1} = \frac{d}{dq} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} q^i$. In addition, we know that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} q^i = \frac{1}{1-q} - 1$. This is where the hint comes in handy:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} i \cdot q^{i-1} &= \frac{d}{dx} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} q^i \\
&= \frac{d}{dx} \left (\frac{1}{1-q} - 1 \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{(1-q)^2}
\end{align*}$$

We can substitute this new finding back into our expression for $E[N]$:

$$E[N] = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} i \cdot q^{i-1}(1-q) = (1-q) \cdot \left (\frac{1}{(1-q)^2} \right) = \frac{1}{1-q}$$

In the second step, we were able to take $1-q$ out of the summation because it does not change with $i$.

Comment: No, not really. Where does the i come from in the second summation? And how do I get the mean waiting time from here?

Comment: Look at the definition of expected value. The term inside the summation is "mass point * the probability of the mass point".

Comment: @PaulBircht I've updated my answer to contain some more hints. Do you see to proceed now?

Comment: Thanks a lot Splitnfinity! But I still don't get how to proceed, sorry!

Comment: @PaulBircht Updated my answer again.

Comment: Oh wow you should be my math teacher ;-) no really, I get it now and thank you very very much SplitInfinity!